# Exponential sum over half-integer matrices

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series

Working in the context of Siegel modular forms, I am interested about whether any closed form is known for the sum $$f(Z) = \sum_{T \ge 0} e^{2\pi i \mathrm{tr}(TZ)},$$ taken over symmetric positive semidefinite matrices $T$ with integer diagonal and half-integer off-diagonal entries, where $Z$ is a symmetric matrix with positive-definite imaginary part.

Even the case of $(2 \times 2)$ matrices, which simplifies to the sum $$f(z_1,z_2,z_3) = \sum_{s,u,su - t^2/4 \ge 0} p^s q^t r^u, \; p = e^{2\pi i z_1} \; q = e^{2\pi i z_2} \; r = e^{2\pi i z_3}$$ seems rather difficult.

Comment: I was just considering the case $Z =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, then isn't $f(Z) = \sum_{T\geq 0} \exp(2\pi i\operatorname{tr}(TZ)) =  \sum_{n\geq 0} \exp(2\pi i n)$. It doesn't seem like it will converge.

Comment: @JackyChong I've added the condition that the imaginary part of $Z$ is positive definite; just like how $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{2\pi i nz}$ only converges when $Im[z] > 0$. I don't think convergence is a problem.

Comment: did you try switching the $\sum_s p^s$ to a sum $\sum_n \frac{1}{z_1-n}$ as for the Eisenstein series ?